# If no match found between two columns do this

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns. I want the formula to pull data from a different sheet and place it into a column that corresponds to the same part number in the first sheet.

Here is what I have so far that's working for me:

**`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,master_inventory_list.xlsx!mt_data, 2, FALSE), "No Exact Match Found")`**

However, in addition to this, if there is no match found, I would like the formula to place the non-matching data from the second sheet and add its entire row to the bottom of the first sheet. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Additional information:

Here is what sheet 1 looks like:

[image]

Here is what sheet 2 looks like:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean if there is a row in the 2nd sheet that is not picked up by the 1st sheet, then you want it added to the bottom of the first sheet?

Comment: @M.L Yes. If no match is found between a part number found on sheet 2 with a part number found on sheet 1, have the part number from sheet 2 and its entire row populate on the bottom of sheet 1 (immediately after sheet 1's last row of data). This is in addition to the formula above. (They need to work together)

Comment: Presuming you can't add a marker column in your second sheet? Else a lookup can be performed there, and then unidentified ones copies over. A sub-question - any chance your part no is numeric and sorted?

Comment: @M.L I'm not sure how I would go about making that formula because for it to know that there's not a match, wouldn't it need to use the formula above to compare the two columns of data so that it knows there's not a match to begin with?

Comment: A sub-question - any chance your part no is numeric and sorted?

Comment: @M.L the part number is a series of numbers and letters. The columns are not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crude solution - works well if you don't have to do repetitive tasks, and if INDEX/MATCH formula are not what you want to play around with due to their clunkiness.

In you sheet2, you can add a column to the left, which matches values of the product no into the Sheet 1 product no column. Formula is `=MATCH(E3,$A$3:$A$7,0)` in the sample screenshot. When it gives an "#N/A", you can filter them product nos out and copy-paste as values underneath the first sheet.

It is a crude method, but I use it if it needs to be done as a one time activity, as against devising a complicated formula (could take time), or a heavy formula which could make the file heavy.

Does that help?

[image]

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. Basically, perform the same formula in sheet 2 and keep the results in sheet 2. Then, filter all the results that show "#N/A" and have their entire row pulled into the bottom of sheet 1. Still, this seems like it's kind of the same thing with the exception of adding an additional column to sheet 2. I still am not sure how to create a formula that would do this and I'm still curious to see if there is a way to do it without having to create crude methods.

Comment: Technically one should be able to do it, I think it can be done via 2-tier INDEX functions coupled with a MATCH function.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to add it as a formula underneath your Sheet 1, it can be done by nesting INDEX and MATCH function.

Let's say your sheet 1 is:

```
Sheet1  
    PN  MT-Data
    1   A
    2   B
    3   C
    4   D
    5   E
```

And sheet 2 is:

```
Sheet 2 
PN  MT-Data
1   A
3   C
2   B
4   D
8   F
7   G
6   H
5   E
```

(Have used them in the illustrative pic)
So, in sheet 1, under PN = 5, you need to find the missing PN from Sheet 2.
The formula to write that cell (A8 in the illustration) is `=INDEX($D$3:$D$10,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($A$3:A7,$D$3:$D$10),0,0),0))`.
[You can understand the inner workings of this by using the Evaluate Formula button]

You can drag this formula down and it will keep popping numbers. When the list exhausts, an #N/A will appear. You will ofcourse need your own VLOOKUP formula that you have to be extended in the column next to it.

Is this what you were looking for? (This seems to be processing the sample data properly, hopefully it fits your purpose)
[image]

Comment: I believe this is on the right path. The only thing I noticed here however is that it will display #N/A and No Exact Match Found at the bottom of sheet 1 (unless I'm mistaken). And what I want to happen is to have the actual part numbers from sheet 2 to appear here if it was decided that there was not a match between the two part number columns from sheet 1 and sheet 2. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) In other words... If I have sheet 1 with a p/n column and sheet 2 with a p/n column, I want the formula to check for comparisons of both of these columns and if "N/A" is a result (meaning there is no match between the two columns), I want the row from sheet 2 that didn't match with sheet 1 to show up at the bottom of sheet 1.

Comment: So in row nos 8,9,10 - it is displaying the missing rows from sheet 2. Cells A8,9,10 are bringing over the PN, and cells B8,9,10 are bringing over the rest of the row? It will start showing N/A when there is nothing to be brought over from Sheet 2. (Else I am not understanding your problem)

Comment: Exactly! Any rows of part numbers from sheet 2 that do not match rows of part numbers in sheet 1 need to be added to the bottom of the list of sheet 1

Comment: Am not good with English words (non-native speaker, so am not able to spot the difference between your comment and what I have done) - can you e.g. in the picture tell me which rows should be carried over from Sheet 2? Let's assume your Sheet 1 has PN 1 to 5.

Comment: _The only thing I noticed here however is that it will display #N/A and No Exact Match Found at the bottom of sheet 1 (unless I'm mistaken)._ - this will happen only after all the PN/MT-Data is transferred over. What is transferred over - all the PN that were missing from Sheet1 but exist in Sheet2.

Comment: Row 24 on sheet 1 in your illustration above should not show a result of #N/A or "No Exact Match Found". Instead, the only results that should appear here are the rows from sheet 2 that did not match sheet 1. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah ok - so you don't want the _#N/A or "No Exact Match Found_! But you are okay with what has transferred across in rows 21/22/23, yeah? I'd thought having an _#N/A or "No Exact Match Found_ would act as a good identifier that you don't have to paste the formula any further than that. Why wouldn't you just delete the row - as in, the missing stuff is all transferred, and the formula doesn't need to exist.

Comment: I have a couple of screenshots to share but am not sure how to display it here

Comment: Am new to this too - maybe add it to your Qn by editing it?

Comment: I added the two sheets above. Under the 'material_transfer' column from the first sheet, you will see a bunch of values that say 'No Exact Match Found'. It's ok for this to stay that way. However, if the result is 'No Exact Match Found' or #N/A, I want the entire corresponding row from sheet 2 to be copied from sheet 2 and pasted to the row below the last row in sheet 1. Don't worry if the rows are wonky in sheet 2. I will be going through that sheet to make sure there are no merged cells.

Comment: Right - I am pretty confused now. It seems that my answer is not relevant, and I am not able to understand the problem (despite looking at the shots). I'd like to take my answer off, in that case; but someone might be able to read our conversation and understand your point better?

Comment: actually...surprisingly, it looks like a little bit of modification, I might have this working. I will try again on Monday and if it's good to go, I'll post an update. Thanks for all the help!